# PLS-00306 with SimpleJdbcCall calling function

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have the next function:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY "CATALOG_NAME" IS

    FUNCTION FUNCTION_NAME (Param1 Varchar2, Param2 Varchar2, Param3 Number)  Return Number;

END;
```

And I'm trying to call it from Java:

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(this.datasource);
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(template)
  .withSchemaName("SCHEMA_NAME")
     .withCatalogName("CATALOG_NAME")
        .withFunctionName("FUNCTION_NAME");

MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("Param1", "value1");
params.addValue("Param2", "value2");
params.addValue("Param3", Integer.valueOf(0));

return simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(Integer.class, params);
```

This is launching the exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{? = call SCHEMA_NAME.CATALOG_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME(?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: PLS- 
00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCTION_NAME'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The first thing I noticed is that the query that is launching has 2 input parameters, instead of 3.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't registered the in and out parameters in the `SimpleJdbcCall`.

Comment: I tried declaring the parameters, but I think that the declaration of parameters is required with a procedure, not with a function (it didn't change anything). Finally I have created a procedure that calls the function internally and that seems to work. However it will be interesting to know what's wrong in this code.

Comment: When the function is called it tries to match the name and/or type. Might be that `Number` doesn't 1-on-1 match with `Integer`? Try enabling debug logging for `org.springframework.jdbc` and check what is being output when preparing and executing the function.

Comment: I noticed that the parameters needed to match the name, otherwise it actually complaints about it and doesn't execute. The function addValue allows you to define the sql type, and I tried with OracleType.NUMBER or the generic Types.NUMERIC. I also tried with Long, BigInteger, BigDecimal... doesn't seem to affect at all. I will check the debug mode to see what's going on.